# Objective-C to Swift bridge

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have to make use of an API which is written in Objective-C but my application uses Swift. I have heard of bridging concept, but I'm not very sure of how to implement it and make use of it in Swift. Is there any other way to make use of Objective-C in Swift?

Comment: Try referring to this link, your question has been answered over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: The bottom line is that while bridging is necessary, it is almost automatic, and is transparent once you've taken a couple of very simple steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, No.

You have to make use of bridge for it. [Check this link (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using bridging header is recommended way and pretty simple. xCode can even auto generate it for you. Follow the instructions here to see how you can implement it and make use of it - http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/